# Java - RestTemplate - Connection Refused

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate

Been running myself crazy trying to solve this, very short this is the code I use to execute a call towards my REST endpoint:

```
String url = "http://localhost:5000/getMyObject";
SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```

But no matter what headers I add it always ends up with connection refused.

Snippet of Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
...
org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
... 74 more
```

Setup: Test running on Windows, Application running in WSL

- It works through Curl (in console and through my test)
- It works if the test itself starts the application
- It works through web browser

Curl -v:

```
localhost:5000/getMyObject
* Trying 127.0.0.1:5000
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 5000 (#0)
> GET /getMyObject HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:5000
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Vary: Origin
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
< Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Sat, 22 Jan 2022 10:05:31 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{<Data>}
```

Comment: What exactly the error you can? Are you getting your object return on curl? What is the error status on restyemplate? Please elaborate

Comment: Was that not clear? Yes, I'm getting data back. I've updated the curl commando with what I get back. Just didn't see the point in including it as the issue isn't what data I get back here. But that the connection is refused. Also included the last bit of the stacktrace.

Comment: Your service is running inside WSL, then you cannot access it from the Windows host using localhost. You need to use the IP-address of the VM of WSL, see [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1609881/89571), or - AFAIK - you need to ensure that the application is actually bound to 0.0.0.0 inside the VM, and that localhost forwarding is enabled in WSL.

Comment: BTW: I guess you're currently using curl from inside WSL, use curl from the Windows command prompt (not PowerShell) instead.

Comment: It works from Windows CMD, WSL CMD and from running curl from the test itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something with SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory just didn't play nicely, I switched it to HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory instead and now it works just fine.

```
String url = "http://localhost:5000/getMyObject";
HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory ();
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(factory);

String result = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
```